# Perform StringBuilder setText method and ExpendableTextView setText method with the same holder

Tags: android, textview, stringbuilder, expandable

Based on the answer given on this post,

[Android - Expandable TextView with Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627530/android-expandable-textview-with-animation)

I want to be able to use my function
`

```
         holder.expandableTextView.setText(wallContent);

            SpannableStringBuilder ssb = SharefolioSpannableHandler.getSpannableStringBuilder(context, wallContent, currentWall.personTagged, currentWall.companyTagged);
            holder.expandableTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            holder.expandableTextView.setText(ssb);
```

`

This is SharefolioSpannableHandler class
`

```
public class SharefolioSpannableHandler {

    public static SpannableStringBuilder getSpannableStringBuilder(final Context context, String text, List<Account> persons, List<Company> companies) {
        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);

        if (persons.size() != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++) {
                final Account person = persons.get(i);
                final String personName = persons.get(i).firstname;

                if (text.contains(personName)) {
                    int start = text.indexOf(personName) - 1;
                    int end = start + personName.length() + 1;
                    ssb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    ssb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                             Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoadUserWallActivity.class);
                             intent.putExtra(LoadUserWallActivity.TAG, person);
                             context.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                }
            }
        } 

        if (companies.size() != 0) {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < companies.size() ; i++) {
                final Company company = companies.get(i);
                final String companyCode = companies.get(i).companyCode;

                if (text.contains(companyCode)) {

                    int start = text.indexOf(companyCode) - 1;
                    int end = start + companyCode.length() + 1;
                    ssb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    ssb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CompanyActivity.class);
                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            b.putSerializable("company", company);
                            intent.putExtras(b);
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                }
            }
        }
        return ssb;
    }

}
`
```

I am currently having some issues as the `ExpendableTextView` which is a holder already has a `setText` but how to include the `StringBuilder` function is giving me problems. If i run as shown above, while it does create the `Expandable TextView`, it doesnt peform what should be done by the `StringBuilder` in terms of links or tags.

Does anyone have any clue on how to join both functions together?

Thanks 
Kingsley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out my issue. I just needed to return the output of my StringBuilder in my ExpendableTextView so instead of this

```
holder.expandableTextView.setText(wallContent);

            SpannableStringBuilder ssb = SharefolioSpannableHandler.getSpannableStringBuilder(context, wallContent, currentWall.personTagged, currentWall.companyTagged);
            holder.expandableTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            holder.expandableTextView.setText(ssb);
```

I did this

```
holder.expandableTextView.setText(wallContent);         
holder.expandableTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
holder.expandableTextView.setText(SharefolioSpannableHandler.getSpannableStringBuilder(context, wallContent, currentWall.personTagged, currentWall.companyTagged));
```

Worked perfectly for me.