# How to scale the view to fit the content size in Android animation?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-animation, android-wrap-content

I am using CardView as a item of Recycler Adapter.

At first, all items will not show the whole content, (I cut it and put the '... ...' instead)
but after click it, the clicked item will scale its height to fit the content height. ( Here I set the text to the whole content and hope the card can scale to fit it )

looks like:

[image]

> I know how to animate the height to the specific target height..
>   but in this case, I don't know how to measure the height needed to show the whole content, each item should have different target height.

How can I do it?

Comment: make sure you are not using maxlines attribute or any similar one

Comment: check this questions [answer] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627530/android-expandable-textview-with-animation)

Comment: @kulvinder Do u mean that the solution which using maxlines has some downsides ?

Comment: the downside of using maxlines is that you can't animate smoothly the lines,  it will show one line at a time. also it applies only to TextView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is ask the `View` to measure itself giving no constraint on its height. Please note the call to `view.getWidth()`, you can do that only after the `View` had been laid out, since you're calling it in `onClick()` it should be fine.

```
int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
view.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
int targetHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Assuming that your View is a TextView with these attributes set:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

the full example would be

```
// this is the height measured with maxLines 1 and height
// to wrap_content
final int startHeight = view.getHeight();

// you want to measure the TextView with all text lines
view.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
view.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

// final height of the TextView
int targetHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();

// this is the value that will be animated from 0% to 100%
final int heightSpan = targetHeight-startHeight;

// remove that wrap_content and set the starting point
view.getLayoutParams().height = startHeight;
view.setLayoutParams(view.getLayoutParams());

Animation animation = new Animation(){
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        view.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (startHeight + heightSpan*interpolatedTime);
        view.setLayoutParams(view.getLayoutParams());
    }
};

animation.setDuration(1000);
view.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: yep, the cool thing is that you can use this technique not only on TextViews

Answer (score 1):

you can do it very simple.
when set a text to TextView for the first time, write this:

```
int minLineNumber = 2;
textView.setMaxLines(minLineNumber); // 2 is your number of line for the first time
```

and when click on that:

```
textView.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE); // set the height like wrap_content
```

if you want the animation, you have sth like this:

```
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(
        textView,
        "maxLines",
        textView.getLineCount());

int duration = (textView.getLineCount() - minLineNumber) * 50;
        animation.setDuration(duration);
        animation.start();
```

if the text in your TextView to too much, it's better to use a fixed duration, not depend on height.

Comment: But, does this start an animation?

Comment: [OOD Waterball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7471830/ood-waterball), i edit the answer with animation.