# Custom Expandable TextView

Tags: android, textview, expandable

I was trying to create a Custom TextView with the expand/collapse capability.

Does anyone have any idea about how to achieve this, extending TextView and overriding onDraw method?? (or any other better approach) ?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627530/android-expandable-textview-with-animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I did it my self, [here](https://github.com/CorradiSebastian/ExpandableTextView) is the repo

https://github.com/CorradiSebastian/ExpandableTextView